# How can I change the start month in the graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating a graph in R that shows the total number of rides per month. Actually, the start month is April 2020 and the end month is March 2021. This arrangement has an important meaning in analyzing and explaining for others. However, since R automatically orders it from 1 => 12 so I would like to ask whether there is another way for me to rearrange this?

```
library(ggplot2);library(dplyr)

Bike %>%
  group_by(member_casual, Date_month) %>%
  summarise(.groups = 'drop',
            average_duration = mean(Time_duration)) %>%
  arrange(member_casual, Date_month) %>%
  mutate(Average_Time = hms(average_duration)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(
    x = Date_month,
    y = Average_Time,
    group = member_casual,
    colour = member_casual
  )) +
  geom_line() + geom_point(size = 3) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Membership Type",
                      values = c(casual = '#ff9900', member = '#0099cc')) +
  labs(
    title = "Average Ride Duration By Month",
    x = "Month",
    y = "Average Time",
    subtitle = "April 2020 to March 2021"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: What is `Bike`? Please ask with [reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038), thanks!

Comment: change `Date_month` to a factor with your preferred ordering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rawr mentioned, you can use `factor` set the order along the x-axis.

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  ggplot(aes(
    x = factor(month, levels = c(4:12, 1:3)),
    y = value,
    group = group
  )) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Membership Type",
                      values = c(casual = '#ff9900', member = '#0099cc')) +
  labs(
    title = "Average Ride Duration By Month",
    x = "Month",
    y = "Average Time",
    subtitle = "April 2020 to March 2021"
  )
```

Output

[image]

Data

```
data <- structure(
  list(
    group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    month = 1:12,
    value = c(
      22.1462195669301,
      34.7227226593532,
      11.3724566600285,
      37.9181093303487,
      11.8698693322949,
      17.4393743579276,
      21.4907402452081,
      17.6362748816609,
      29.6476712427102,
      36.9375107018277,
      25.3655201010406,
      20.449273835402
    )
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -12L)
)
```

Comment: Thanks all of you :> I found other ways to solve this. I extracted date_month with the year so the result is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the year as well you could use the package `lubridate` to create a date and plot that along the x-axis instead. Then the order should be fixed and I think the names look better as well.

Building on Andrew's example, we could do something like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data %>% 
  mutate(date = lubridate::make_date(year = year, month = month)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(
    x = date,
    y = value,
    group = group
  )) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Membership Type",
                      values = c(casual = '#ff9900', member = '#0099cc')) +
  labs(
    title = "Average Ride Duration By Month",
    x = "Date",
    y = "Average Time",
    subtitle = "April 2020 to March 2021"
  )
```

Output:

[image]

Data:

```r
data <- structure(
  list(
    group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    month = 1:12,
    year = c(rep(2021, 3), rep(2020, 9)),
    value = c(
      22.1462195669301,
      34.7227226593532,
      11.3724566600285,
      37.9181093303487,
      11.8698693322949,
      17.4393743579276,
      21.4907402452081,
      17.6362748816609,
      29.6476712427102,
      36.9375107018277,
      25.3655201010406,
      20.449273835402
    )
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -12L)
)
```